# Checking for nil before releasing an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory

Is this good or bad practice?

```
if (!theConnection && !receivedData) {
        // release the connection, and the data object
        [theConnection release];
        // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
        [receivedData release];
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending any message to nil object has no effect, so you can safely remove that check.

Moreover your code leaks memory in case only 1 of the object is non-nil.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad practice - just look through Apple's sample code to get a feeling for how it should like.

Use `[theConnection release];`

or `[theConnection release]; theConnection = nil;`

and the same for `receivedData`.

Comment: This works with every local variable or property. With (retaining) properties you could just use self.theConnection = nil; although I won't advocate to do this from dealloc.